# Renaming Project causing 'unexpected error'

Tags: java, jsf, netbeans, web-applications

I created a project with all the functions working perfectly. However, when I go to rename the project in netbeans, it does change the name and does compile but the AJAX auto-complete function stops working. I also can't access 'Project Properties' because the error below keeps appearing:

This never use to happen and don't understand why it would suddenly start.

**'Unexpected Error'**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid ClassPath root: file:/C:/Users/Khalid/Desktop/facupprediction/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/. The root must be a folder.(exists: true file: false directory: true read: true write: true root: null _root: C:\Users\Khalid\Desktop\facupprediction\build\web\WEB-INF\classes@b6d84463:c6dc28)
    at org.netbeans.api.java.classpath.ClassPath$Entry.getRoot(ClassPath.java:806)
    at org.netbeans.api.java.classpath.ClassPath.createRoots(ClassPath.java:284)
    at org.netbeans.api.java.classpath.ClassPath.getRoots(ClassPath.java:268)
    at org.netbeans.api.java.classpath.ClassPath.findResource(ClassPath.java:448)
    at org.netbeans.modules.spring.api.SpringUtilities.containsClass(SpringUtilities.java:175)
    at org.netbeans.modules.spring.api.SpringUtilities.containsSpring(SpringUtilities.java:156)
    at org.netbeans.modules.spring.beans.ui.customizer.CustomizerCategoryProvider.hasSpringOnClassPath(CustomizerCategoryProvider.java:126)
    at org.netbeans.modules.spring.beans.ui.customizer.CustomizerCategoryProvider.createCategory(CustomizerCategoryProvider.java:87)
    at org.netbeans.spi.project.ui.support.ProjectCustomizer$DelegateCategoryProvider.readCategories(ProjectCustomizer.java:745)
    at org.netbeans.spi.project.ui.support.ProjectCustomizer$DelegateCategoryProvider.getSubCategories(ProjectCustomizer.java:706)
    at org.netbeans.spi.project.ui.support.ProjectCustomizer.createCustomizerDialog(ProjectCustomizer.java:257)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.project.ui.customizer.CustomizerProviderImpl.showCustomizer(CustomizerProviderImpl.java:126)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.project.ui.customizer.CustomizerProviderImpl.showCustomizer(CustomizerProviderImpl.java:106)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.project.ui.customizer.CustomizerProviderImpl.showCustomizer(CustomizerProviderImpl.java:102)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.actions.CustomizeProject.actionPerformed(CustomizeProject.java:150)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.actions.LookupSensitiveAction.actionPerformed(LookupSensitiveAction.java:170)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:699)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:710)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:162)
[catch] at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: Maybe `Project / Clean`?

Comment: Netbeans is definitely messing with you. Clean the project (not clean-and-build); build the project; then deploy.

Comment: Since only the classes from `org.netbeans.*`, `javax.swing.*`, `java.awt.*` get affected, the exception is only related to the NetBeans IDE. JSF has got absolutely nothing to do with problem. Java class files (`.class`) under `build/web/WEB-INF/classes/` cannot be located for some unclear reasons. The class-path is corrupted.

Comment: Still getting the same error. I think it's the netbeans on that specific computer because when I go to create a new project and rename it straight away, I get an error. But no problem on other computers.

Comment: The NetBeans IDE on that specific PC may have been corrupted or may have some lurking bugs already. Are you parallel with the IDE's version on different PCs?